# WSDL generated files

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soap, wsdl

I've created a Web Application (with JSP) that uses a SOAP server endpoint to do some operations. I use gradle to automate the build. My problem is that when I run WebApp, it does not find the WSDL generated classes (and I've specified them in build.gradle).

My source files of servlet are in **/src/main/java/servlets** and generated WSDL files are in **/src-gen/main/java/todo_soap**.

Here my WebApp **build.gradle**:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath (group: 'com.sahlbach.gradle', name: 'gradle-jetty-eclipse-plugin', version: '1.9.+')
    classpath 'org.gradle.jacobo.plugins:gradle-wsdl-plugin:1.7.6'
    classpath 'org.gradle.jacobo.plugins:gradle-jaxb-plugin:1.3.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.wsdl'
apply plugin: 'com.github.jacobono.jaxb'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jettyEclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()                                               
}

dependencies {
   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
   jaxws "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.8"
   jaxws "com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.2.8"
}

//
// See the documentation of this plugin at
// https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-wsdl-plugin
// 

wsdl {
  wsdlFolder = "src/main/wsdl"
  wsimport {
    sourceDestinationDirectory = "src-gen/main/java"
    wsdlLocation = "http://localhost.com:8081/toDoSOAP?wsdl"
  }
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += wsdl.wsimport.sourceDestinationDirectory
compileJava.dependsOn wsimport 

//
// Required by XJC because toDoSOAP.xsd is a file
//

System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
```

[My full project here](https://github.com/javiertello/Lab1/tree/master/ToDo_SOAP_WebApp-ws)

Comment: We definitely need more information. What does not find what exactly? Is there any error message or stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your code. Below is an example of the missing info that [Martijn Courteaux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155137/martijn-courteaux) requests:

```
/Users/javier/Downloads/Lab1-master/ToDo_SOAP_WebApp-ws/src/main/java/servlets/ToDoAddServlet.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        ToDoWebServiceService twss = new ToDoWebServiceService();
        ^
symbol:   class ToDoWebServiceService
location: class ToDoAddServlet
```

The reason of the error is that you forgot to add `import todo_soap.*;` in the file `ToDoAddServlet.java`. If you look at `src-gen\main\java` you can see that the generated code belongs to the package `todo_soap`.